# Make href attribute in <a> Tag reactive

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I have the following HTML code:

```html
<input id="number" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10"> <a href="/products/add-to-cart/<%= products[i]["_id"] %>" class="btn btn-light">Add to cart</a>
```

This code displays an input number field and a button that links to a route for express.

My question is, how can I get the number entered in the input field as a parameter to the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag?

I need to also send the quantity the user wants to add to the shopping cart, to my route so I can add that to the cart.

Your help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Turn the anchor into a form? Or use Javascript to set/append the input value to the URL  (`?name=value`) upon loss of focus?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use an `onClick` Javascript function

Answer (score 1):

Listen for the change event to be fired on the `input:number` node, then just reset the `href` attribute on the anchor node, as shown in the example below. Could also just use a `click` event handler to `window.location` to the created URL or switch to a `form`

```js
document.querySelector('#number')
  .addEventListener('change', evt =>
  {
    const value = evt.target.value;
    document.querySelector('a').href = `/products/add-to-card/${value}`;
    console.log(`HREF is now : ${document.querySelector('a').href}`);
  }, true);
```

```html
<input id="number" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10">
<a href="/products/add-to-cart/1" class="btn btn-light">Add to cart</a>
```

Comment: `(() =>` what is this?

Comment: `(() => {})();` is an IIFE. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression